# CocoaPods: Installing a library that contains an embedded framework

Tags: cocoapods

When installing a library that contains an embedded framework, it seems that the framework needs to be linked to the application target manually.

Is there any way this can be properly automated?

Examples are:

- Dropbox-iOS-SDK
- Reveal-iOS-SDK
- NewRelicAgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework search paths needs to contain the following (note the *recursive* setting):

[image: Search Paths]

. . As far as I know, CocoaPods sets this up, so it must've been unset in the project(s) where this was occurring.

Comment: I'm having this issue and have tried your solution. Am I doing this right? http://d.pr/i/Iow9 I'm still getting red/broken frameworks: http://d.pr/i/AvuP ... any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. Have you tried manually adding a framework? Choose link with framework/lib, 'Other', navigate into the Pods directory, project name and find the .framework file in there. . . should force it to work, though you probably also want to know what the root cause is.