# How do I use Cocoapods in an embedded framework?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, xcode6

I'm using an embedded framework for my custom views in a new project to take advantage of the new @IBDesignable stuff in Xcode 6 and I'd like to animate said views with Facebook's Pop. I've added Pop to the project using Cocoapods but the embedded framework doesn't have access to those files (`'POP/pop.h' file not found`).

I tried copying the Cocoapods-related build phases from the app target to the custom framework target but they don't work as-is. What *does* work is copying the Pop folder into the embedded framework directly, but then Xcode tells me that I've gotta change all of the angle brackets `<POP/pop.h>` to quotes `"POP/pop.h"`. I'm assuming there's a better way and I'm blanking on it.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465348/cocoapods-installing-a-library-that-contains-an-embedded-framework

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Assuming in your Podfile you are using the `link_with 'MyCustomFramework'`, where 'MyCustomFramework' is your embedded framework name, and have run `pod install`. Select your Project file (Blue on the top right) and go into "**Build Settings**". Then, find '**Allow non-modular includes in Framework Modules**' and set it to **YES**, for both the Project file (blue) and the Custom Framework target (ex. MyCustomFramework - orange "lunchbox case" icon).

[image: Setting build settings for non-modular includes]

Then you can include cocoa pods stuff in your main MyCustomFramework.h file.
[image: Including CocoaPods in CustomFramework]

Then just import '@import MyCustomFramework;' in your Application target, and you'll get the rest of the CocoaPods at your disposal. (Ex. showing you access to 'each' from ObjectiveSugar).
[image: Importing CustomFramework into AppDelegate]

Whether you should do this or not is a separate issue, but this allows your Custom Framework to include the CocoaPods libraries in itself, which then allows the Application target to just include your Custom Framework and gets all the CocoaPods as well.

Sorry for the multiple images, but I like to be visual.

Comment: This looks promising, the issue that I am encountering is that when I try `#import "AFNetworking.h"` or many variants, it fails to compile saying the file is not found. Meanwhile in any other class within the framework the import works fine. It seems that my framework header can't see AFNetworking?

Comment: Awarding you the bounty before it expires... hoping that you can solve my import issue to wrap up the question. Thanks.

Comment: Started a project from scratch to test this out and it all seems pretty sound, but when I hit build I still get a couple errors: `/Users/rich/Desktop/Popso/PopsoKit/PopsoKit.h:10: include of non-modular header inside framework module` (which seems odd, seeing as I changed the build settings) and `<swift-imported-modules>:1: file '/Users/rich/Desktop/Popso/PopsoKit/PopsoKit.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/rich/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/3TJ94BS85RO52/PopsoKit-4FRELWU8OWUI.pcm' was built`. I'll keep poking and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Well, it looks like the Xcode 6 Beta 3 resolves this issue entirely: `Views that opt in to Interface Builder live rendering are now supported from within your application and no longer require a framework.`

Comment: @ChrisWagner, did you make sure you are using angle brackets? `#import <AFNetworking.h>` works as it is also part of my custom framework. Also check to make sure your Podfile is setup properly so that the embedded framework target properly sees all the header files from Cocoapods.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Looks like this stopped working in Beta 5 though.

Comment: Can someone upload an example project on GitHub please?

Comment: Could you post the Podfile of yours? What if I want to use the same pod in multiple targets including cocoa touch framework?

Comment: For this approach, is it necessary that my Podfile contains "use_frameworks"?

Comment: What are we supposed to do now that link_with is no longer supported?

Comment: I believe that this does not work if the framework must support iOS7. Any ideas with respect to iOS7?

Comment: the link_with  is deprecated.. what is its alternative?

Comment: i have exactly the same problem with Xcode 9 and swift 4.2 .. is there any update on this procedure?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are modifying the framework to use Pop. In this case you'll also need to add the Pop headers' path to the framework Build Settings' search header paths.

But then if you're modifying the framework you could just create a [podspec](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html) for it as well and let CocoaPods handle everything (and send a pull request to the creator?).

---

As for the bounty question.

A framework should never embed other libraries. If for instance you want to use AFNetworking in your library:

- State that AFNetworking is required in your own framework installation instructions.
- If you distribute binaries you just build locally against AFNetworking headers. Users will need to provide their own AFNetworking when linking their App.
- If you distribute source code with your framework (if users have to build it themselves) then ask in your installation steps to set the AFNetworking headers path in your frameworks  Build Settings Header Search Paths and preset it to common paths such as `POD_ROOT`, etc.

Then it works but you have complex installation instructions, users have to manually add resources if any, it is hard to control the AFNetworking version being added by users and most will never upgrade your framework because it may break their setup. All good reasons to support CocoaPods by creating a podspec (you can keep maintaining the framework/static library project if you really want).

Comment: Perhaps I should have started my own question rather than putting a bounty on this. But I figured it was closely related. In my case I want to include Pods in my Embedded Framework but access them in my App's target (I am working with extensions). So, my embedded Framework wants `AFNetworking` but my App could also benefit from `AFNetworking`. Currently if I set `AFNetworking` as a dependency for both targets I get some runtime errors saying that the usage is ambiguous since both the App binary and Framework binary have the same APIs. And only including it in the framework dependency...

Comment: Prevents usage in the App target, the compiler doesn't see any of it.

Comment: Great points @Rivera, I hadn't thought through the consequences.

Comment: Would this be of concern for the purpose of embedded frameworks for App Extensions though? There's no intent to distribute the framework itself, it's merely to support the multiple targets within the project.

Comment: One more reason to avoid the hassle to maintain an iOS framework just for yourself.

Comment: Do we have a choice? I was under the impression in order to share code between App Extensions and the container app you need to create the embedded framework and link to both targets?

Comment: @ChrisWagner Not necessarily - you could add the files to both the app extension and the app itself - there is some duplication but it seems less complicated the framework - esp if there is swift involved.

Comment: You could also just turn your CocoaTouch framework into a local private pod that has its own subspec dependencies on CocoaPod libraries.

Comment: Is it possible to do what you've described using Cocoapods? It seems like you'd want the apps consuming the embedded framework to link against the third party libraries and the shared framework code to just know about the headers? Maybe Cocoapods simply isn't the right tool for this project structure?