# Using Cocoapods in embedded framework with Xcode 6 GM

Tags: xcode, frameworks, swift, cocoapods

Here's my configuration :

1. `Pod X` : Linked with `MyProjectSharedCode`, declares class `SomeClass` (in *Objective C*)
2. `MyProjectExtension` : Today extension, sharing data with `MyProject`
3. `MyProject` : Companion app to configure `MyProjectExtension`
4. `MyProjectSharedCode` : Embedded framework for common code in `MyProject` and `MyProjectExtension`. Uses `SomeClass`.

I can't get it working. I've tried :

- Importing `PodX.h`in `MyProjectSharedCode.h`, but it results in a compiler error :

> include of non-modular header inside framework module

- Which lead me to a few Stackoverflow links, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175697/how-do-i-use-cocoapods-in-an-embedded-framework). However, changing this option didn't allow me to compile either. As @NachoSoto says in the accepted answer's last comment, the answer doesn't seem to work since Xcode 6 B5.

Any help/leads would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't link code with a framework. You reference its headers to compile but nothing is linked just yet. Only the host app links all the compiled binaries.

Comment: I gave it a try : Linked both apps with the pods, as it currently is. Added a new target. Updated Header search path to include `Pods` folder. Removed `Common` folder, re-added the files with only the framework as a target. Builded. Each Swift file failed to compile with the error : `<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'LiFXWidgetSharedCode'`

Comment: First. I did not solve the problem. Last attempt was to build pods with "Defines module" in pod project (as in doc _"When you import an external framework, make sure the Defines Module build setting for the framework you’re importing is set to Yes."_). But. I don't know exactly, but I think not all pods source code is recompiled every build time, some pods are just static libs with headers. So, no modules are defined, and you can see the error from the question. Smb could try to recompile pod sources with defined module name AND public scope headers (they are project by default in pods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good post that came out today about using the development branch of Cocoapods 0.36.0 which is where frameworks/swift support is being added.

http://swiftwala.com/cocoapods-is-ready-for-swift/

Baring that I've been linking pods into a framework and then including the headers in the bridging header. Its a little wacky but it works so long as you don't want to write swift that uses the pods in the framework itself.

**Edit**
The pre-release version of 0.36.0 is out [you can see the blog post here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/).